# Can't decide between a better CPU vs better GPU for graphic design and some video editing

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, desktop

I have to build a PC and I have limited money. I may upgrade CPU or GPU in future though. But I can't decide which one would be more important for tasks like *graphic design apps (Adobe, Affinity etc.), 1080p video editing on daVinci Resolve*.

Graphic design is primary task whereas video editing in Resolve is like my hobby or secondary task. Might do basic VFX too for learning or hobby work. Nothing serious work.

---

I know preferences for hardware depends on people and their clients and their expectations and where their clients are based from. To give a general idea about what I had been using before to do this work (except Resolve), it was a Dell Inspiron laptop with i7 8550U processor and 940MX graphics card.

This laptop's CPU has basically 4 cores. It was mostly fine for my personal work and where I used to work. It was slow in video editing but didn't limit my work like photo editing and illustration and other design tasks.

But at this moment, it's definitely little slow for me because I want to do some personal video editing work too. And I need a little better overall experience in design related tasks.

---

So now I decided to shift to desktop instead. **I have largely two choices:**

1. i3 12100F processor + GTX 1660 Super GPU
2. i5 12400F processor + GTX 1650 GPU

*(I will buy 32GB RAM no matter which choice I finalize)*

I really can't decide if **CPU or GPU** would be more important for my tasks. If I go with 1), I will upgrade CPU later. If 2), I will upgrade GPU later.

I don't know what option of these two would be a good start for now.

Comment: Both are a good upgrade from your laptop. I would personally prioritize CPU since those are harder to upgrade later

Comment: @Irsu85 On laptop GPU is harder to upgrade. As far I know it´s even not posible at all to upgrade GPU for laptop.

Comment: @convert I think he meant for desktop because I'm upgrading to desktop from laptop.

Comment: Yes I see that on the CPU model number. If it ends with "U", "H", or "G" and then a number it is a laptop CPU (on Intel at least). All other cases are desktop CPUs

Comment: @Irsu85 CPU hard to upgrade because of motherboard compatibilities issues?

Comment: And you have to remove the cooler and clean it. Gpu is just swapping one card